# Switching Between href and ui-sref

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Currently I have a page that is populated from a news controller.

**news.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="article in newsController.news">
<a title="Click to view" href="{{article.location}}" target="_blank">
    <div class="eventHolder">
        <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
        <hr />
        <p>{{article.description}}</p>
        <p class="date">{{article.date}}</p>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

**format of news.controller.js**

```
var newsPage = angular.module('myApp');
    newspage.controller etc etc...

    ...
    self.news = [
        title:
        description:
        date:
        location: "img/blabla.pdf"
```

So if the location is a pdf then it is fine. The issue is I need  some of the pages are actual html pages so they need to use `ui-sref` instead of `href`. I was thinking of adding another attribute to the page like `page: true` and add an `ng-click` to the html to check if it is a pdf (or a page). That will determine whether to use `ui-sref` or `href`.

I am not sure how to "send" the `ui-sref`/`href` parameters to the html from the controller. Or if I am even doing this correctly. Apologies if anything is unclear.

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION**

The reason it has to use ui-sref is the page is managed by a $state provider which is also giving it information for it's css. (It does not have it's stylesheet on the page).

Comment: I think you can simply use `href` to point the link to the URL of another state. of course you need the `/#/` at the beginning of the url as well.

Comment: some of the pages are using a `$state.provider` which gives it some functionality and it also gives it the css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a field in `news` like this:

```
self.news = [{
  ...
  isPage: true,
  ...
}]
```

Then in the HTML, you can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to decide to use `href` or `ui-sref`:

```
<a ng-if="article.isPage" ui-sref="{{article.location}}">
  ...
</a>
<a ng-if="!article.isPage" href="{{article.location}}">
  ...
</a>
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for but is there a way to do this in one tag? It is kind of useless to me if I am specifying it in each `<a>`.

Comment: Well, you can always create a directive for that. Or, if the `news` object is an array, you can always use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: This worked great. I got confused initially since I thought you were adding multiple <a> tags when I already ng-repeat. Thanks!